# Parallel IO read on a single file

Tags: c#, .net, file, io

I'm trying to read a pretty large file (around 4GB) and parse it. I make use of producer/consumer and reads file line by line with offloading it for processing. Is this possible to parallelize  reading of single file itself by starting multiple IO threads reading file by chunks and pass it to consumer from multiple threads? I was searching about and it said better to use one thread for IO and then do parallelization, can someone elaborate on this please ?

Comment: The speed at which you can read from a file on disk is limited by how fast the disk is. Your processor can handle the data far faster than the disk can read it. Adding more threads won't make your disk any faster -- it still has the same maximum read speed. You can easily read as fast as your disk can support with a single thread: adding more threads don't change that. If the disk is spinning rust, adding multiple threads will make the read slower, as the disk constantly has to seek between the sections being read at the same time

Comment: Try looking at the Task Parallel Library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl

Comment: well, if you're reading from _one device,_ you can only read one chunk of data at a time. if you're opening two read streams, the maximum performance of your device won't increase. but the actual performance will decrease (especially with hard disk drives), since it has to switch between the two streams.

Comment: Note that if you split the data into multiple independent buffers, parsing this will be challenging, since there will probably be lines that are part of multiple buffers, and that needs to be handled somehow.

Comment: Another point is to *measure*. Reading a 4GB file should only take a few seconds on a modern SSD. Profiling should reveal if you have any other bottlenecks in your code. Do not assume that processing is optimal or even fast enough just because you use a producer/consumer pattern.

Comment: @JonasH Do you mean some specific method (line by line) or any method should read generally within a few seconds?

Comment: @IRCodder a good SSD have a bandwidth of round 1-4GB/s. So moving the data from file to memory should be fairly fast. "Reading lines" would be one step of parsing the data. Doing various kinds of measurements should help determine what part is in most need of improvement, and there techniques like `span<char>` that can be used to avoid the need for copying data.